From bootup, delay or rush the login and screen goes blank?
Sometimes when I login to my laptop, from bootup, delay or rush the login and the screen goes blank?  The only way I can get back in is via a hard shutdown (long hold to on/off button).
Why is this?
Using Ubuntu 24.04.1 LTS, on a Lenovo Ideapad 720 - i7-7500U.  Continually check for updates so nothing pending there ("The software on this computer is up to date").
Any help pointers welcome.
Thanks
Dave
